# ProgrammingError 1064 doing CREATE TABLE AS SELECT from an existing table with MySQL in Python

Tags: python, mysql, pymysql

I have an existing table in the cloud and I want to make a copy of it. I connect to my database via pymysql, extract the username from an input provided from the new user, and I want to create a new table that will be called by the username, and that table will be a copy of the original one. When I run the code below, I have the following error:

`pymysql.err.ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''username' AS SELECT * FROM original_table' at line 1")`

```
uname = blabla@bla.com
conn = pymysql.connect(
                    host="db.host",
                    port=int(3306),
                    user=user,
                    passwd=password,
                    db=db,
                    charset='utf8mb4'
                )
                cur = conn.cursor()
                table_name = uname.replace('@', '_').replace('.', '_')
                print('TABLE NAME:', table_name)
                cur.execute(""" CREATE TABLE %s AS SELECT * FROM original_table """, (table_name))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parameter quoting is for quoting *values*.  Quoting table names does not work, because in MySQL the way to quote a table name is by using backticks (`), not quotation marks.

```
MariaDB [test]>  CREATE TABLE 'username' AS SELECT * FROM my_table;
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ''username' AS SELECT * FROM my_table' at line 1
```

In this cause you need to use string formatting to create the SQL statement (you can use backticks to defend against SQL-injection<sup>*</sup>):

```
cur.execute(""" CREATE TABLE `%s` AS SELECT * FROM original_table """ % table_name)
```

<sup>*</sup> I'm not an expert on SQL-injection, so do some research if `table_name` originates outside your application.

Comment: It works @snakecharmerb! I did not know that, thank you very much!
As a follow-up question, the newly created table has an unfriendly name (`'username'`) with the backticks (sorry we can't see the backticks here) and single quotes; do you happen to know a way to make it more attractive?

Comment: Where are the quotes coming from?  Are you still using `cur.execute(stmt, tbl)`?  It needs to be `cur.execute(stmt % tbl)` or `cur.execute(stmt.format(tbl))` (or some other of Python's infinite string formatting variations)

Comment: I made a mistake when I used your code; I kept the table_name in between parentheses with a comma and the format changed the name to the username surrounded with quotes and backquotes. I made the proper changes and it's perfect. Thanks again!